# Calculate average of selected cells in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to mark cells from a column then store the range into a variable. I would like to use the variable for another macro to calculate the average from the given range.

```
Sub UserRang()

Dim SelRange As Range

Set SelRange = Selection
Rng1 = SelRange.Address
MsgBox "You selected: " & Rng1

End Sub


Sub GradeAve()

GradeAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Rng1)
MsgBox "The grade average is: " & GradeAverage

End Sub
```

Comment: what have you looked into?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use the AVERAGE worksheet function and skip the 'variable' in the middle?

ex. "=AVERAGE(A1:A5,A9,A12)"

VBA isn't great if you want to save and maintain static variables (or something resembling static variables).

Comment: It's because it is an assignment and my professor wants me to this even though i agree with you that it would've been much easier.

Answer (score 0):

`Rng1`needs to be declared on top of the module and should be a range not an address string as `Average`needs a range as argument.

```vb
Public Rng1 as Excel.Range  

Sub UserRang()
Dim SelRange As Range

Set SelRange = Selection
Set Rng1 = SelRange
MsgBox "You selected: " & Rng1.Address

End Sub
```

Even better, use a function that returns the range instead of a sub.

```vb
Public Function GetUserSelection() as Excel.Range
  Set GetUserSelection = Selection
End Function

Sub GradeAve()

  GradeAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(GetUserSelection)
  MsgBox "The grade average of " & GetUserSelection.Address & " is: " & GradeAverage

End Sub
```